# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar(update) varias filas a la vez?

Tags: php, mysql

Por ejemplo tengo una tabla llamada "tabla1" en MySQL con los siguientes valores.

- Fila 1: 100
- Fila 2: 80
- Fila 3: 50

Quiero actualizar cada fila restando 10 unidades, para que al final quede así:

- Fila 1: 90
- Fila 2: 70
- Fila 3: 40

Haciendo la siguiente consulta me sale bien:

```
$resta=10;

$sql = "SELECT valor FROM tabla1";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $auxiliar=$row[0]-$resta."<br>";
}
```

Con esto me devuelve lo que quiero, es decir, resta 10 unidades a cada fila correctamente (Esto es solo la consulta, lo que yo quiero es actualizar los datos en MySQL).

Probando lo siguiente, lo que hace es que me resta el primer valor y se queda todo igual (pone todas las filas en el valor 90), lo pongo para que lo veáis pero está mal.

```
$resta=10;

$sql = "SELECT valor FROM tabla1";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $auxiliar=$row[0]-$resta;
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tabla1 SET valor='$auxiliar'");
}
```

Si no queda claro lo intento poner mejor. Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al hacer `UPDATE` no estás indicando que registró quieres actualizar, y por ende, todos los registros se ven afectados.

### Soluciones:

- Usando solo una consulta `SQL` podrias actualizar todos registros, sin necesidad de tener que hacer un por uno. Así por ejemplo:

  ```
  $resta=10;
  $sql = "UPDATE tabla1 SET valor = valor - $resta";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  ```
- Usando `PHP` y asumiendo que cada registro tiene un `ID único`, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

  ```
  $resta=10;

  $sql = "SELECT id, valor FROM tabla1";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $auxiliar=$row[1]-$resta;
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tabla1 SET valor='$auxiliar' WHERE id = $row[0]");
  }
  ```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ese era el problema! Funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

Te cambia todo porque no tienes una condición podrias probar con:

```
$resta=10;

$sql = "SELECT valor FROM tabla1";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
$auxiliar=$row[0]-$resta;
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tabla1 SET valor='$auxiliar' where valor='$row[0]'");
}
```

Ejemplo:

Cambiara todos los campos valor por 90 donde el campo tenga 100, es decir cambiara $row[0] (Que es el valor que tienes inicialmente) por $auxiliar que es tu valor nuevo.

Te sugiero que si tienes algun ID o algun otro campo que te ayude en la condición ya que esto te va a cambiar todos los 100 en la primera iteración que encientre y si encuenta 10 cien te va a hacer el UPDATE 10 veces aunque desde el primero que encontro ya cambio todos.

Comment: Sierto, la costumbre.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese era el problema. Pensaba que al querer actualizar todo no habia que poner un where. Gracias!